# How to get RedirectToAction to use relative path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using `RedirectToAction` to redirect to a different view, however I'm using an application in a site in IIS so there is a prefix that has to go to the path.

When I do `RedirectToAction` it just redirects on the root.

I need it to respect the current path and redirect along those lines.

For example:

I'm on `https://localhost:8085/app/custompath/controller1/action`

and I call
`return RedirectToAction("controller2", "action");`

and I get redirected to

`https://localhost:8085/controller2/action`

instead of

`https://localhost:8085/app/custompath/controller2/action`

Comment: What is custompath? Where should ASP.NET MVC know it from. I think you should edit your default routes in `RouteConfig.cs` and add the custompath to your routes

Comment: Wouldn't that break the routes?  I'm using urlrewrite in IIS so MVC doesn't expect a custom path when finding a view.

Comment: Hmmmm I think you are right. But then why isn't there a rewrite rule to rewrite `https://localhost:8085/controller2/action` to `https://localhost:8085/app/custompath/controller2/action`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like this in your `Starup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "custom",
                template: "app/custompath/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
```

Then you can do this to redirect:

```
var url = Url.RouteUrl("custom", new { controller = "controller2", action = "action" });
return Redirect(url);
```

By the way .NET Core has built-in [URL Rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x) if you need.

Comment: This would work but it will break when he moves the site somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

`RedirectToAction`, or any of the similar methods that let you generate a URL based on route information like controller, action, name, etc. only work for the currently running application in context. You cannot use them to generate URLs for routes in other applications.

You *can* use simply `Redirect` with a string URL, but it's on you to generate the URL you need. The typical approach is set the base path for your external application in an application setting.

Comment: I think this is a single application. It just has a subfolder as the root.

Comment: No, that would then be a sub application. It doesn't matter if they exist in the same folder hierarchy. They're still separate applications.

Comment: I think he is redirecting within a single application, but he has set up the website as a sub application. That's why he has this problem.